# Extract a list of files from tape with tar

Tags: tar, tape

My goal is to extract only the files in a list from an lto5 tape using tar. The data was originally written to the tape using tar as well. I am able to accomplish this task from a .tgz file by doing:

```
gunzip < file.tgz |tar --directory /local/projects/devel/tar_test -x -v -T test_input
```

Where `test_input` is a list of files to extract. That works fine but I am having trouble doing the same from tape. When restoring data from tape I typically do:

```
tar -x -v --file /dev/tape/fixed/drive0 --directory /local/projects/devel/tar_test
```

I've tried adding the `-T test_input` to this command but it fails. I believe the failure is related to this from GNU's tar manual page:

> "Unless you are running tar with ‘--create’, you cannot use both
> --files-from=- and --file=- (-f -) in the same command."

Because it is not possible to use the --file and --files-from (-T) options together, I'm wondering if it's even possible to restore specific files from tape this way? I've seen others have had to position the tape at different points to get specific files and am curious if that is the only method?

Comment: To restore a single file from tape requires reading the entire tape, end to end, then a rewind to find the one file. You _can_ put this in a shell loop and do it for every single file, but that will quickly get tedious. When I've had to do this, and it's been like once in 30 years, I just read the whole tape to disk, did the thing from disk like normal, and trashed the on-disk copy when done.

Comment: Bishop I don't think that's true. You go over the tape linearly and extract every file that matches the list. No rewinding necessary -just like in the tgz case, what rewinding isn't possible, either.

Comment: The quote you included from the man page says that you cannot have both the tar archive and the files to be extracted both read from stdin. It is certainly possible to use both `--file` and `-T` together. What is the exact error message you get when you try to extract the files?

Comment: You have not told us what the error message is. However I looked at the manual, and it does not show `--file` as on option for extract (`-x`). Have you considered `<`?

Comment: You have misread the man page. There are `-` at the end of both those example options. You **can** use `--file` and `--files-from` in the same command: you just cannot assign them **both** to stdin (as represented by `-`).